# Automate Azure SQL Server database restores

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two SQL server databases running on Azure - one Prod and one Test. I want every night, the Test server will automatically sync its data and structure (include any TABLE, Stored Proc changes ) with Prod - so Test is a mirror of Prod that can be used for development / QA.

I am wondering how to achieve this on Azure? Please note I would like this to happen automatically and on a schedule. Thanks everybody.

Comment: What I suggest you do is work out what PowerShell commands you need to do your job, then schedule them in Azure Automation. You'll probably need to delete your test and restore prod to a new db. Or do some tricky renaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure the moment, we can use Azure data sync service to sync data between database. But we cannot use the service to sync  Stored Procedures. For more details, please refer to [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd396fb5-2be7-44af-afaa-467295139422/adding-stored-procedures-to-a-azure-data-synced-sql-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#sync-req-lim). So if we want to sync Stored Procedures, SQL Server Management Studio Generate Scripts Wizard is an easy means of producing a script that will copy all of your Stored Procedures to another database.

Besides, regarding how to create a schedule to start azure SQL data sync, please refer to the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/schedule-data-sync-with-azure-sql-database-use-an-automation/ba-p/368988)